# how to send a chart with custom data with document studio google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm trying to get data from Google Forms and use the inputs to create individual charts for each person that responded and send them to each person as a PDF, using Document Studio Add-on.

I managed to send the PDF with that particular data as text, but I didn't manage to create the chart with that individual data.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: Welcome! If you want to create a Sheet graph from FOrm data, please take a look at the [graph guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts). If you still need help, please share your actual code so we all can take a look. In addition to that, please show some examples of the desired result.

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron,

I will try to explain in detail what I want to achieve

1) After a person completes the google From - I want to create a simple chart (nothing fancy) only with some of the numerical inputs.
2) Then I'd like to place that chart in a PDF and send that PDF to that particular person.

To send emails to the persons' who completed the form I'm using Document Studio Addon.I managed to send data as a PDF but i can't find a way to create a chart in that PDF with the desired data.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I now grasp your scenario. Please share the code so we all can take a look and help you. If needed, I beg you to take a look at the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron There is no code.